# Grep a value start and end

Tags: bash, curl, grep

I want to ask something make me so confused.
i try to curl url. and i need to get some header.

```
Set-Cookie: csrf_token=AQD_HUQgacFx24NaG2k-haMOIHzJK75x8qazU25yOmeC8_hpT7fJGte_3eZlp6EUCSo-5B8vonrccR3Q3TY-esSA6SIYJhzz9_N1AH7LqchvbSmYHGv0U8UL84hVKi-c-yfWgcs;Version=1;
```

i was try to use. `grep -oP '(?<=Set-Cookie: csrf_token=)[^"]*')`
but it will get all value after csrf_token=

```
AQD_HUQgacFx24NaG2k-haMOIHzJK75x8qazU25yOmeC8_hpT7fJGte_3eZlp6EUCSo-5B8vonrccR3Q3TY-esSA6SIYJhzz9_N1AH7LqchvbSmYHGv0U8UL84hVKi-c-yfWgcs
```

i just need the value after `=` and before `;version=1;`

Answer (score 0):

Use `[^;]` instead of `[^"]` if that's what you actually mean.

Answer (score 0):

Try this command

```
[root@localhost]# awk -F';' '{split($1,arr,"="); print arr[2]}' <<< "Set-Cookie: csrf_token=AQD_HUQgacFx24NaG2k-haMOIHzJK75x8qazU25yOmeC8_hpT7fJGte_3eZlp6EUCSo-5B8vonrccR3Q3TY-esSA6SIYJhzz9_N1AH7LqchvbSmYHGv0U8UL84hVKi-c-yfWgcs;Version=1;"
AQD_HUQgacFx24NaG2k-haMOIHzJK75x8qazU25yOmeC8_hpT7fJGte_3eZlp6EUCSo-5B8vonrccR3Q3TY-esSA6SIYJhzz9_N1AH7LqchvbSmYHGv0U8UL84hVKi-c-yfWgcs
```

and as @tripleee mentioned

```
[root@localhost]# grep -oP '(?<=Set-Cookie: csrf_token=)[^;]*' <<< "Set-Cookie: csrf_token=AQD_HUQgacFx24NaG2k-haMOIHzJK75x8qazU25yOmeC8_hpT7fJGte_3eZlp6EUCSo-5B8vonrccR3Q3TY-esSA6SIYJhzz9_N1AH7LqchvbSmYHGv0U8UL84hVKi-c-yfWgcs;Version=1;"
AQD_HUQgacFx24NaG2k-haMOIHzJK75x8qazU25yOmeC8_hpT7fJGte_3eZlp6EUCSo-5B8vonrccR3Q3TY-esSA6SIYJhzz9_N1AH7LqchvbSmYHGv0U8UL84hVKi-c-yfWgcs
```